# How has psychology categorised different types of love?

Tags: social-psychology, emotion, physical-attraction, love

How has psychological theory categorised the different types of love?
What taxonomies of love are most accepted or useful in psychology?

**EDIT:**
I went through [Triangular theory of love.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_theory_of_love) Are there any other theories like this out there?

Answer (score 1):

Sternberg's Triangular theory is certainly well-known. The field you want to dig into more is called 'close relationships'. Here's an accessible treatment of other common theories:

> Summary of psychological theories of love https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/in-love-and-war/201208/love-decoded

This gives a good theoretical overview using many different approaches:

> More abstract positioning of theories of relationships and attachment with relation to other fields http://www.wwnorton.com/college/psych/intimate-relationships/ch/03/summary.aspx

Here's another I learned about in grad school:

> Bem - Exotic Becomes Erotic: Interpreting the Biological Correlates of Sexual Orientation
>   http://doi.org/10.1023/A:1002050303320

Comment: Can you please provide a brief rundown of what you will find when clicking the links? This is in case the links break at a later date. Also, when linking journal articles, it is often best to link using the doi link as doi links rarely break in comparison to others.